# Bash: sort filenames with chromosomes

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a folder of files that all look like this

```
ASX.chr.txt
```

where `chr` can be a number of 1-19, X, Y or MT.

Is there a way to sort these files that I get the following order?

```
ASX.1.txt
ASX.2.txt
ASX.3.txt
...
ASX.9.txt
ASX.10.txt
ASX.11.txt
...
ASX.19.txt
ASX.X.txt
ASX.Y.txt
ASX.MT.txt
```

Comment: From where do you want to sort them? From `ls` output?

Comment: You might want to look into the `sort` command and its arguments.

Comment: @fedorqui: yes, `ls` output.

Comment: `ls -l sort=version` almost makes it, at least for the digits.

Comment: I don't see why `MT` should be after `Y`

Comment: because MT is a mitochondrial chromosome and the usual ordering is numbers, X, Y, MT

Comment: The file system isn't intended as an all-purpose database, and to the extent that the file system is a *kind* of database, `ls` isn't an all-purpose query tool for it.

Comment: I'm really scared that genetic computing is done with the shell. I see that again and again. I mean don't you have access to other programming languages? Do your professors encourage you to use the shell?

Comment: If you have perl: `ls ASX.*.txt | perl -e ' $i=0; $o{ "ASX." . $_ . ".txt\n" } = ++$i } for (1..19, qw/X Y MT/); print sort { $o{$a} <=> $o{$b} } (<>);'`

Comment: why not .... `echo ASX.{1..19}.txt ASX.{X,Y,MT}.txt` is more simple

Answer (score 0):

I like @pii_ke's perl oneliner.  However, if you don't have perl, you can try this —

```
ls | sed 's/\.M/.30M/;s/\.\([XY]\)/.20\1/'|sort -t. -k2 -n|sed 's/\.[23]0/./'
```

(in bash)

- The first `sed` changes `X->20X`, `Y->20Y`, `MT->30MT`
- the `sort` sorts on the part after the first `.` and before the second (`-t. -k2`), in numeric order (`-n`).  So `X` and `Y` come after `19`, because of the `20`, and `MT` comes after those, because of the `30`.
- The second `sed` undoes the effect of the first.